# Azure SQL database type

Tags: web-services, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am making a MVC website that has a SQL database for storage on Azure. Potentially there will be many hundreds and possibly thousands of transactions per day to the website via a web service.

What type of database should I use? Should it be the web retired version, standard or any of the other types? What is the cheapest, that still works well with the traffic of many hundreds and possibly thousands of transactions per day.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description of your requirements equates to a *light transaction workload* - "hundreds and possibly thousands **per day**".  It's difficult to give a concrete answer with such little information.  However, assuming you're OK with the 2GB database size, the Basic tier is where I would start.  You can always change your service tier and/or performance level if you find you need more.

Be sure to check the [Overview of the Performance Model chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn741336.aspx) to find the service tier and performance level that meets your requirements.  Notice that Basic benchmarks are per hour, Standard are per minute, and Premium are per second.

Also, look at the [SQL Database pricing page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn741336.aspx) and you will see the pricing for a Basic is going to be cheaper than an equivalent Web Tier.